# How to navigate to different views on a button click using navigation link?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to navigate to different views based on a variable value using navigation link. Could you please help on this

Answer (score -1):

Use **NavigationLink(destination: , label: )** as follows:

```
struct TestView: View {

   var viewName = ""

   var body: some View {

       VStack {
           
         NavigationLink {
                if viewName == "firstView" {
                    FirstView()
                } else if name == "secondView" {
                    SecondView()
                } else if name == "thirdView" {
                    ThirdView()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Go to specified view")
            }
       } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done it using NavigationStack.

Example:- Initially shouldShowAgeView is false. When `"Show DOB"` button is clicked, we will change `shouldShowAgeView` to true and when it is true `AgeView` will be shown.

```
struct DetailView: View {
@State private var shouldShowAgeView = false
@State private var shouldShowDOBView = false
@State private var shouldShowWeightView = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Button("Show DOB", action: showDob) // showDob function will be called on when tapped on the button
            Button("Show Age", action: showAge) // showAge function will be called on when tapped on the button
            Button("Show Weight", action: showWeight) // showRollNumber function will be called on when tapped on the button
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $shouldShowAgeView) { // if is true then AgeView is shown
            AgeView()
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $shouldShowDOBView) { // if is true then DOBView is shown
            DOBView()
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $shouldShowWeightView) { // if is true then WeightView is shown
            WeightView()
        }
    }
    .onAppear{
        shouldShowAgeView = false
        shouldShowDOBView = false
        shouldShowWeightView = false
    }
}

func showAge() {
    shouldShowAgeView = true
}

func showDob() {
    shouldShowDOBView = true
}

func showWeight()  {
    shouldShowWeightView = true
}
```

}